# How to create Work Shifts clock AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am learning right now scripts functionally in Google Sheet, however, can't twist my head around constructing a very simple App script.

I have the following table (Snoopi Tab)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l6nYBAqB1GWoMkIOwlykhiuMpaXdWHTo7UhgZdq6hT8/edit?usp=sharing

I want it to do this simple action:

EXAMPLE:  If today is not Sunday or Saturday and the date is 14.2.14 and cell BF5 is
---> go down 3 rows and paste current time "Clocking in" working-shift

```
When button "IN" is clicked:
If (TODAYDATE = Value in cell in row 5) & (row 3 ==!"S") both true

    Set current time in (same column just row 8)
```

Same with "OUT" button, but this I'll try to figure by myself.

Comment: I can't see where your button `IN` is located in the **Snoopi** tab. If you could include a screenshot for the **before** and **after** state of the sheet when the button is clicked, that would be great.

Comment: Here is the Screenshot,https://ibb.co/PNsSx2s, its on the left side, so I am basically using both

Comment: Hi @Shavlen, I have provided a working answer below with a sample output, test the script and it should also work for you. This script worked on the copy I made from your sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is acceptable, but is very resource intensive and have a lot of loops to do resulting to very slow execution time especially when it gets later on the year since it will loop all those dates.

Also, the run you did on the other answer did finish successfully but didn't write anything due to it missing the actual date value. This might have been caused by a timezone issue, or by only modifying the actual date while getting the raw time of the cell value.

A better alternative would be to make use of the 4th row where it contains `x` value when the date is equal to the current date. By using that, you wouldn't need to loop thus resulting in faster execution time and wouldn't need to convert time thus making it safer. As long as row 4 is populated on all columns (which your problem is), there should be no issue of using this script.

#### Script:

```
function WorkClock() {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // you only need 3rd and 4th row of data
  var data = sheet.getRange("E3:NE4").getValues();
  // 4th row contains 'x' when today matches the column, find that index
  var indexToday = data[1].indexOf('x');
  
  // if that column's row 3 is not 'S'
  if(data[0][indexToday] != 'S')
    // write the time on row 8
    sheet.getRange(8, indexToday + 5).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(currentDate, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'HH:mm'));
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- Timezone used is based on the spreadsheet's timezone which is GMT-8. Wherever the user is, it will use GMT-8, not its local time which should be helpful in some cases.
- Performance difference between this and looping all dates would be vast if we are now dealing with the later months of the year (e.g. November, December)
- For the OUT button, create another function by duplicating the current function. Then replace where you write the time. Instead of row 8 (Start), write it in row 10 (Finish).

Comment: I can't express how thankful I am for your not only extended explanation but also providing an additional GIF for it! This is beyond any help I ever received on this community! And secondly, I am very impressed by your ability to understand external factors that affect scripts in Google Apps. Big kudos and continue contributing!

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {
  var actualDate = new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).getTime();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange("E3:NE6").getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
    if (data[2][i].getTime() === actualDate) {
      if (data[0][i] !== "S") {
        sheet.getRange(8, (5+i)).setValue(new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes());
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's an interesting approach to set variable i=0, but I've attached the script to the Button, but it doesn't deploy the time even though it says that the script ran successfully, can you navigate me please?

Comment: @Shavlen, it did finish successfully, but didn't write as it wasn't able to find the condition mentioned above. most likely caused by a timezone issue or by only modifying the actual date while getting the raw time of the cell value. See the other answer I provided. It should work better.